Prove that the sequence $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{\ln{a_n}}$ converges
Given $a_0=e^{3/2}$ and $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{\ln{a_n}}$ prove that the sequence converges. I have made a graph of $f(x)=\frac {x}{\ln x}$ and $y=x$ and seems that $an \to e$ as $n\to \infty$. Now, my try: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\ln{a_{n-1}}}\leq 1$. If $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\ln{a_{n-1}}}<1$ then from the ratio test we got that the series converges to $e$, and if $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\ln{a_{n-1}}}=1$ we got that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\ln{a_{n-1}}=1$ which happens only if  $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n-1}=e$

the derivative at the fixpoint $e$   is zero. Convergence is swift, oscillates above/ below

@WillJagy Do you have any reference with some theory on that?

several pdfs at http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/ecalle.cgi   and http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Iteration.cgi

As $a_n = \phi(a_{n-1})$ we have  $a_n - a_{n-1} = \phi'(\eta)(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})$ and for $\eta > 2\Rightarrow|\phi'(\eta)|<1 $ so converges Cauchy style.

Take $b_n=\ln a_n$. Then $b_0=\frac{3}{2}$, and $b_{n+1}=b_n-\ln b_n$. As $b_0>1$, prove by induction that $b_n>1$ for all $n$, using $\ln(x)<x-1$. Then you get $b_{n+1}=b_n-\ln b_n < b_n$, which means that $b_n$ is decreasing and bounded below by 1, thus it converges to a limit $l$ satisfying $l=l-\ln l$. So $l=1$ and $a_n\to e$. You can also work out the proof directly with $a_n$, without going through $b_n$.

The function $f(x) = {x \over \ln x}$ and satisfies $f([e,\infty)) \subset [e,\infty)$ and $f'(x) \in [0,{1 \over 4}]$for $x \ge e$. In particular, $f$ is a contraction and hence the sequence $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ converges (with $x_0 \ge e$).
